# Primary Key from 1 to 01, 2 to 02, etc

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a primary key field (news_id) in the news table

it start from 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on..

However, I like to change to 01, 02, 03, 04,e tc ... is that possible?

If not, how can that be done in PHP?

Comment: What do you need this for? Manipulating the keys like this is a bad idea. The best way to go is most likely to change the format when outputting the keys.

Comment: If you just want to "01" format for output, you can just convert the id to string after getting results from DB

Comment: @Pekka it is for output, example. domain.com/news/031 (Google News prefer this method when submitting)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Manipulating the keys directly is a bad idea in 99% of cases.

The best way to go is probably to change the format when outputting the keys like shown in [this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896510/generate-integers-with-leading-0s)

```
$key = 4;
echo sprintf('%02d', $key); // outputs 04
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's for output, just add a 0 if the primary key is less than 10:

```
if($result['id'] < 10){
   echo '0' . $result['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay... Another way of doing this is... (though overly logical and mathematical...)

```
$id = 5;
$noOfZeros = 2; // i.e. you are converting 2 to 002.
$divider = pow(10,$noOfZeros); // Now you are creating a divider (/100 in this case)
$id = $id / $divider; // dividing the id by 100. i.e. 5 gets converted to 0.05
$zeroedId = str_replace(".","",$id); // finally replace the "." with nothing... so 0.05 becomes 005 :).
```